# How to replace one records with many (ie explode a group into pieces) when entering?

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to figure out the best approach for something - I have added an additional table to the Sales Order screen as a new tab and it works fine to save records into it. The next thing needed is to potentially explode a value into many lines if it is a certain type. So if they enter a "kit" into my grid/tab - we would want to replace the kit with its components and not have the kit in the grid anymore.

I know how to insert the records etc. My biggest concern is which event to do the work under (field or row level and -ed vs -ing) . I know I could potentially create an endless loop if I don't do it properly.

**edit - I tried using RowInserting - I can cancel the inserting and add my records in there - however it does not trigger the screen to refresh from the cache. If i Save the order - it will display my new rows properly. however, i dont want to do a save in my code. I am also concerned about it triggering another rowinserting.

With rowinserted - it seems to be the same with the screen not refreshing and also i get an error about the row that i deleted.

Comment: Thks to Gabriel, the view.RequestRefresh() was what i needed to synch the cache and display.  Still uncertain on my overall approach - but it seems to be working using RowInserting..

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar request and what we did is instead of adding the item in grid level and waiting for a trigger, we added a grid tool bar button that pops up a small smart panel to select the kit item, its version and the quantity required. Then we inserted the component lines to the grid with required calculations.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is a more logical way to proceed. In my case this functionality is only there for a third party to integrate with and they have already designed it around the scenario described or i would change it to what you suggest.  I finally my piece to work, but just feel like it is a bit sketchy.